# Open .pdf or other document outside the app

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm writing a macOS app with `Swift` which stores documents, that are retrieved from a webserver, in the appcontainer aka sandbox.

Then I wish to open these documents with another application by clicking a button, edit the document in the application it gets opened with and then save it.

Is there a possibility to do this?

Comment: Please read [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is certainly possible when not constrained to the sandbox and you can probably create a small test app to confirm this.  Will your application require app store / sandboxing?